# JQuery Toggle True or False on data-filter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image link which I want to use as a toggle button.

```
<img id="myToggleButton" src="myToggle.jpg" />

And what I want it to toggle is this:

<ul id="listview" data-filter="true">

So, basically I need to change from data-filter="true" or data-filter="false" and so on.
```

How can I get this working using JQuery?

Comment: Are you using this markup with a jQuery Mobile listview widget? In that case, you will probably have to refresh the widget (`$("#listview").listview("refresh");`) after setting the `data-filter` attribute.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$('#myToggleButton').click(function(){
   var $listview = $('#listview');
   $listview.attr('data-filter',
       $listview.attr('data-filter')=='false' ? 'true' : 'false'
   );
});
```

Comment: simplifying `$listview.attr('data-filter')=='false' ? 'true' : 'false'` to `!JSON.parse($listview.attr('data-filter'))`

Answer (score 3):

Something along the lines of ?

```
var $list = $('#listview');
$('#myToggleButton').click(function (event) {
  if($list.data('filter') == true) {
    $list.attr('data-filter', false);
  }else {
    $list.attr('data-filter', true);
  }
});
```

Comment: The setter form of `data()` does not create or update `data-` attributes, even though its getter form does read them if nothing is associated with the element in the data cache.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I should of probably known this as I recently came across that problem, it just makes sense logically in my head that it should be able to set them.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more succinct and modern jQuery way using the `data()` method to handle data attributes:

```
$('#myToggleButton').click(function (){
  var listview = $('#listview');
  listview.data('filter', !listview.data('filter'));
  listview.listview('refresh');
});​
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UupNd/) as well so you can see it in action.

Comment: Now issue `alert(listview.attr("data-filter"));` and you will see `data()` did not actually modify the `data-filter` attribute.

Comment: the ``data-filter`` is already set in the HTML he provided, you don't need to use jQuery or JavaScript to set it.

Comment: Ah sorry I misunderstood what you were saying at first, I see what you're saying now however I'm not sure how important that is. If it were important that it updates on the HTML element as well you think jQuery would include that.

Comment: I guess that depends on how you interpret the question, and the libraries used by the questioner :) Although (for instance) jQuery Mobile uses `data()` to fetch the value of the `data-filter` attribute, so you can safely use `data()` to set it as well, other code can query the attribute itself.